# Mapping mouse events to key presses using xbindkeys

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool, xbindkeys, xte

I want to map various mouse actions to key presses using `xbindkeys`. All my attempts to do this in my `.xbindkeysrc` file have failed. Attempts have been made using `xte` and `xdotool`. Below is a summary of what has been tried - although I'd like to map several mouse actions so far I've just been trying to initiate a right-button mouse click.

The following `xdotool` and `xte` commands work perfectly when called from a terminal, from the graphical pop-up `Run Command` text-box, and from within a script called from the terminal and the `Run Command` text-box. It is only when called using keys set in the `.xbindkeysrc` file that they fail.

```
Entries from .xbindkeysrc:

"xdotool click 3"
    control + 8

"xte 'mouseclick 3'"
    control + 7

# -x :0 sets the display.
"xte -x :0 'mouseclick 3'"
    control + 6

# Starting a text editor window works fine.
"leafpad"
    control + 1
```

I also had no luck placing the same commands (one at a time) in a script and calling that in `.xbindkeysrc`. I added a command at the bottom of the script to create a file - the file gets created every time so I know that the script is being run successfully.

```
"/full/path/to/mouse/button/script"
    control + 5
```

Please note that there have been no silly mistakes like not restarting `xbindkeys` after making alterations, I've been checking that it is running and added a command to `.xbindkeysrc` which launches a text editor window so that I can be sure `xbindkeys` is running properly.

```
System Info.
OS:        GNU/Linux x86_64
Kernel:    3.13.0-24-generic
Distro:    Linux Mint 17 Qiana, Cinnamon 64-bit 2.2.16
           [Based On: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr]
```

Comment: Just tested your first entry using `xev`; it works fine on my system. Which sequence of events do you see with `xev` for this entry (Ctrl-8)?

Comment: I've put the `xev` output for the first 3 commands in a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/b787992e7a54db4b6505a1c0e7eaeb3e) - it looks like the mouse event takes place but no right-click menu ever actually gets displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Tested again with fvwm and firefox, right-click menu for the first entry (Ctrl-8), both menus appear. What applications did you use to test for a right-click menu?

Comment: Various; Terminal, Sublime Text, Nemo, Firefox, the desktop. Why would the application make a difference?

Comment: Just trying to find a hint why it works on my system, but not on yours. I've honestly no idea where to look next.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem after finding [this post](https://superuser.com/a/552411/350242) on Superuser. It says there is a bug which can be worked-around by adding a short pause. The following `.xbindkeysrc` entry now works.

```
"sleep 0.25 && xdotool click 3"
    control + 8
```